# EstablishContactKey for Contact Event SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to trigger a journey using SOAP API. It works for the existing contacts, but not for new contact. In REST API, there is a property called EstablishContactKey. Does anyone know how to set EstablishContactKey to True in SOAP API?

```
{
    "ContactID":
    "EventDefinitionKey":
    "EstablishContactKey": true, // To insert new Contacts
    "Data": {}
}
```

```
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Options />
    <Objects xsi:type="ContactEvent">
        <Client>
            <ID></ID>
        </Client>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <EventDefinitionKey></EventDefinitionKey>
        <Data>
            <AttributeSet>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                <Name></Name>
                <Items>
                    <Item>
                        <Values>
                            <Value>
                                <Name></Name>
                                <Value></Value>
                            </Value>
                        </Values>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
            </AttributeSet>
        </Data>
    </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
```

Comment: why aren't you using the rest api to inject contacts into a journey?

Comment: @EazyE REST API and Triggered Send are not options. The request goes through IBM DataPower Gateway and only the ContactEvent SOAP API format pass the DataPower validation.

Comment: the contact event is a legacy entry event, and the subscriber had to exist within all subs or a population first, you will need to first add these subscribers to the all subs through API before using this contact event